# JSON Parsing. value not comes in Kilometers

Tags: iphone, ios, json

i am new programmer.i am using Google Matrix API. i get the following response i wants fetch  "text" : "1686 km". i am using Json Parsing. Thanks

```
"destination_addresses" : [ "San Francisco, Californie, États-Unis" ],

   "origin_addresses" : [ "Vancouver, BC, Canada" ],

   "rows" : [

      {

         "elements" : [

            {

               "distance" : {

                  "text" : "1 686 km",

                  "value" : 1685690

               },

               "duration" : {

                  "text" : "3 jours 21 heures",

                  "value" : 336418

               },

               "status" : "OK"

            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}



  SBJsonParser *json = [[SBJsonParser new] autorelease];

  NSError *jsonError;

  parsedJSON = [json objectWithString:data error:&jsonError];
```

Comment: Use SBJSON Library for parsing your document go to following link https://github.com/stig/json-framework. In that link also u getting one sample code of JSON parsing.

Comment: What have you already tried to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `parsedJSON` will be an `NSDictionary` so:

```
NSArray *rows = [parsedJSON objectForKey:@"rows"];
for (NSDictionary *row in rows) {
    NSArray *elements = [row objectForKey:@"elements"];
    for (NSDictionary *element in elements) {
        NSDictionary *distance = [element objectForKey:@"distance"];
        NSString *kmDistance = [distance objectForKey:@"text"]; ///< That's what you wanted
    }
}
```